# Insert many rows to Oracle Database very fast

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I need to insert many sql rows into oracle database very fast. IndexData is the class which contains save method to insert into oracle database.

```
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    if(line.contains("numDocs")) {
        numDocs = in.readLine().trim();
//For Inserting 
IndexData id = new IndexData(timeStamp, 1, 2, numcDocs);
id.save();
    }  else if(line.contains("indexSize")) {
        indexSize = in.readLine().trim();
//For Inserting 
IndexData id = new IndexData(timeStamp, 1, 3, indexSize);
id.save();
        } else if(line.contains("indexReplicatedAt")) {
   replicationTime = in.readLine().trim();           
//For Inserting         
IndexData id = new IndexData(timeStamp, 1, 4, replicationTime );
id.save();
    } 
    }

    BufferedReader inUrl   = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (isUrl));
    String lineUrl;
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("<str name=\"status\">(.*?)</str>");

    while ((lineUrl = inUrl.readLine()) != null) {
    if(lineUrl.contains("str name=\"status\"")) {
        Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(lineUrl);
        if (regexMatcher.find()) {
        status = regexMatcher.group(1);
//For Inserting
IndexData id = new IndexData(timeStamp, 1, 5, status);
id.save();
        }                   


}  
}
```

And this is my IndexData class-

```
public IndexData(String timestamp, String serveId, String informationId, String value ) {
this.timestamp=timestamp;
this.serverId=serverId;
this.informationId=informationId;
this.value=value;
}
//For Inserting
public void save() throws SQLException {

ps = DataSource.conn.prepareStatement (
"INSERT INTO table(timestamp, serverId, informationId, value) VALUES(?,?,?,?)");

ps.setString (1, timestamp);
ps.setString (2, serverId);
ps.setString (3, informationId);
ps.setString (4, value);

ps.executeUpdate();
ps.close ();
}
```

Is this the best way to insert into oracle database having several multiple sql statement for insertion. As I am opening IndexData class again and again for inserting only one row into DB for each information. Is there any other way that is faster than this. Any suggestions will be appreciated..

Comment: How many is "many"?  Hindreds?  Thousands?  Millions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at [`PreparedStatement.addBatch`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#addBatch%28%29) and [`PreparedStatement.executeBatch`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeBatch%28%29) - you can create a single prepared statement, add several sets of parameters for of execution, and then execute the batch. You probably want to choose some number of inserts per batch though, limiting the amount of "pending" work building up in memory.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Can you give example based on my code. As per your suggestions I have to modify the save method in IndexData class. right?

Comment: @RaihanJamal: You'd need to change your code to either move the `save` method out of `IndexData`, or have a static method in `IndexData` to save a `List<IndexData>` or something similar. That method would prepare the statement, then loop over the items to add, setting parameters and calling `addBatch` lots of times, then calling `executeBatch` - possibly doing all of *that* in a loop to limit the size of the batch.

Comment: @Jon Skeet You need to execute/clear the batch every xxxx records (1000 or more) for minimize memory usage.

Comment: @SergeyGazaryan: Yes, hence my last sentence :)

Answer (score 2):

This will never scale very well, but it depends how many records need to be loaded. Generally a better option is to use direct path load with sql loader and potentially load in parallel.

Comment: +1  Oracle comes with several methods for load information from a file into the database: SQL Loader and External Tables are the usual approaches.  A bulk-oriented approach using provided functionality is always going to be faster than a hand-rolled RBAR implementation, no matter how well tuned.

Answer (score 1):

I feel bad smell in your design, like your entity object is responsible for creating and closing the prepare statement, database connection is "global" etc.

There are some common way that you can look into:

1. Perform prepare statement only once and use it for multiple update
2. Use Batch Insert/Update

However, both way needs you to revisit your design (but I think it is worth doing so).

(And, if you are posting your code, please make sure you properly indent it.  It is simply a mess now)

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is to write the queries to a file and load the file into DB in a separate thread. 
This is because all your quires are just insert queries. This has a glitch although that if the loading of file fails then you don't know where its wrong. This way you can reduce the memory foot print and work faster is what I guess.